# Replace resource only when variable value has predefined value

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, terraform

Is there I way to trigger resource replace only when some variable value has some predefined (config value) value

I want to create mongo db certificate only if certificate is going to expire in less than month.

I tried

```
locals {
  expire_in_less_than_month =     timecmp(mongodbatlas_x509_authentication_database_user.backend.current_certificate.not_after, timeadd(timestamp(), "768h")) == -1
}

resource "terraform_data" "replacement" {
  input = local.expire_in_less_than_month
}


resource "mongodbatlas_x509_authentication_database_user" "backend" {
  project_id              = mongodbatlas_database_user.backend.project_id
  username                = mongodbatlas_database_user.backend.username
  months_until_expiration = 6
  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [
      terraform_data.replacement 
# this will always trigger replaces when this value change but I  want to trigger replace only when replacement has value 1, when it is 0 I do not want to recreate this resource
    ]
}
```

Is there I way to trigger resource replace only when terraform_data.replacement value has some predefined (config value) value

Comment: What's the problem with performing a replacement when the value changes? When it performs the replacement, the value will then be 0, and will stay at 0 until the certificate is nearly expired, at which time it will be replaced and the value will still be 0 (so no further replacement). I guess I'm also asking "what happened when you tried that?"

Comment: Have you looked at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/rotating

Comment: @lxop It will create 2 certificates in consecutive deployments. Certificate is created, terraform_data.replacement = 1, in one point it will be -1 and because values has changed we do replacement. In next deployment  terraform_data.replacement is again 1, and there will be one more replacement. And than values stays 1.

Comment: In Terraform this sort of behavior with "expiring" objects is normally handled as a feature of the provider itself rather than something you would need to implement separately using hacks in your module. I would expect the `mongodbatlas_x509_authentication_database_user` resource type to offer a setting to specify how many months before expiration the object should be renewed, and then the provider would test during plan whether the expiration time is within that window and propose to replace the object if so. The `hashicorp/tls` provider's `tls_self_signed_cert` has an example of that pattern

Comment: With all of that said, I'd suggest opening a feature request with the provider developer to suggest adding this feature. Having the provider handle it directly is the most robust answer, because it has total control over when it reports that a resource instance needs to be replaced.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @MartinAtkins

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @ChisDoyle